# Hive XML SerDe - XPATH

Tags: xml, xpath, hive, hiveql

I have the below XML

```
<qr>
    <Trade xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ss="http://www.mycomp.com/mycall/schema/1/durables/ss" xmlns:ss-raw="http://www.mycomp.com/api.dsl/tm/2/ss-raw/v1.0">
        <TradeId>
            <ss:SYSTEMID>1466413528</ss:SYSTEMID>
        </TradeId>
        <InstrumentId xsi:nil="true">test_instrument</InstrumentId>
        <TraderSourceSystemName xsi:nil="true">akjsdfklas</TraderSourceSystemName>
    </Trade>    
</qr>
```

I am trying to load into a Hive table using

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE sample(TradeId STRING,
    InstrumentId STRING,
    TraderSourceSystemName STRING
    )
    ROW FORMAT SERDE 'com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml.XmlSerDe'
    WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
    "column.xpath.TradeId"="Trade/TradeId",
    "column.xpath.InstrumentId"="Trade/InstrumentId/text()",
      "column.xpath.TraderSourceSystemName"="Trade/TraderSourceSystemName/text()"
    )
    STORED AS
    INPUTFORMAT 'com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml.XmlInputFormat'
    OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.IgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
    LOCATION "hdfs://server:port/user/sl/sample/"
    TBLPROPERTIES (

  "xmlinput.start"="<Trade xmlns",
  "xmlinput.end"="</Trade>"
      );
```

When I select * from the table, the first field is shown like below

```
<pre>
<TradeId><ss:SYSTEMID xmlns:ss="...namespace...">1466413528</ss:SYSTEMID></TradeId>
```

How to the trade id like - `1466413528`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"column.xpath.TradeId" = "Trade/TradeId/*[local-name(.)='SYSTEMID']/text()"
```

---

```
create external table sample
(
    tradeid                 string
   ,instrumentid            string
   ,tradersourcesystemname  string
)
row format serde 'com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml.XmlSerDe'

with serdeproperties 
(
    "column.xpath.TradeId"                  = "Trade/TradeId/*[local-name(.)='SYSTEMID']/text()"
   ,"column.xpath.InstrumentId"             = "Trade/InstrumentId/text()"
   ,"column.xpath.TraderSourceSystemName"   = "Trade/TraderSourceSystemName/text()"
)

stored as
inputformat     'com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml.XmlInputFormat'
outputformat    'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.IgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'

tblproperties 
(
    "xmlinput.start"    = "<Trade xmlns"
   ,"xmlinput.end"      = "</Trade>"
)
;
```

---

```
select * from sample
;
```

---

```
+------------+-----------------+------------------------+
|  tradeid   |  instrumentid   | tradersourcesystemname |
+------------+-----------------+------------------------+
| 1466413528 | test_instrument | akjsdfklas             |
+------------+-----------------+------------------------+
```

> **Limitations**
> ...
> Only the XPath 1.0 specification is currently supported. The local
> part of the qualified names for the elements and attributes are used
> when handling Hive field names. The namespace prefixes are ignored.
>
> https://github.com/dvasilen/Hive-XML-SerDe/wiki/XML-data-sources

Comment: Thank you sir, let me test it and get back to you

Comment: Works.. Trade/TradeId/*[local-name(.)='SYSTEMID']/text()
thanks a lot Mr. Markovitz

Comment: Hello Markovitz, do you know if I can perform concatenation on the xml nodes and load the value into one column in Hive.
I tried concatenate / string-join, but its not allowing me to load into the field for eg: in my ` "column.xpath.TradeId"       I would like to concatenate the values from "Trade/TradeId/*[local-name(.)='SYSTEMID']/text()" and Trade/TraderSourceSystemName/text() ` fields

Comment: No luck so far. I'll have to dive into the code but it will take me some time to get to it. I would suggest that in the meantime you'll open a new query for this.

Answer (score 0):

Use xpath `//Trade/TradeId/ss:SYSTEMID/text()` for `column.xpath.TradeId`

Comment: Have you tested this?

Answer (score 0):

How to create Hive a table on op of this xml.

```
    <root>
<root1>
<id>4545482361</id>`enter code here`
<joiningdate>1/3/2010</joiningdate>
<Segments>
<Segment xse:type="manager">
<cityworked>Hyd</cityworked>
<reports>john</reports>
<salary>150000</salary>
<datestarted>1/3/2012</datestarted>
</Segment>
<Segment xse:type="manager">
<cityworked>Hyd</cityworked>
<reports>mike</reports>
<salary>225000</salary>
<datestarted>1/9/2014</datestarted>
</Segment>
<Segment xse:type="VP">
<cityworked>mumbai</cityworked>
<datestarted>1/9/2014</datestarted>
<subemployees>
<Fname>ram</Fname>
<Lname>Achanta</Lname>
<Desgination>Director of IT</Desgination>
</subemployees>
</Segment>
<Segment xse:type="SVP">
<Staus>currentposition</status>
<numberofemployees>10</numberofemployees>
</Segment>
</Segments>
</root1>
</root>
```